# SmartGWT Calendar Width and Height

Tags: gwt, calendar, smartgwt

I've tried setting an explicit width and height to the calendar widget in the SmartGWT library using calendar.setWidth(500) and calendar.setHeight(400) to no avail.

Any ideas why this wouldn't work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luminari at #gwt on freenode suggested I use a SimplePanel to wrap the calendar and size it down then add it to the TabBar. Thanks!